# Ubuntu 22.04 is stuck on logout screen following a download failure

Tags: boot, 22.04

I tried to download Ubuntu 22.04 from Ubuntu 20.04. Every time I start the computer I got this error message.

```
Oh no, something has gone wrong. 
A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. 
Please log out and try again.
```

When I press Enter (the mouse cursor is not on the screen), the screen goes black for a few seconds and the same screen pops up again time after time. The only way to turn computer off is force power it off or pull out the cable. At start-up I get the same screen again; it is stuck. I tried power up/start holding down, clicking non-stop space and Shift keys (individually, together, alternately), but I couldn't get anything else to happen.

Comment: "Tried to download 22 from 20 versions" needs more explanation. Which version exactly were you trying to upgrade from (in the yy.mm format). Did you back up any vital data beforehand? Please use [edit] to amend your question - not comments.

Comment: This problem is not non-reproducible in Ubuntu 22.04, and it shouldn't be closed for that reason. It is reproducible in Ubuntu 22.04 and so is the solution in the asker's self-answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I read someone suggested pressing Ctrl Alt F2 / Ctrl F1 but nothing worked. I kept unplugging it, starting up hitting Space / Shift keys, but after 3-4 times I gave up. When I started the computer again, bingo I was in BIOS. I have an Ubuntu 18.04 live USB on a flash drive, changed the start-up options in the BIOS Boot tab, and got a working machine.

I'll consider updating to Ubuntu 20.04 or
Ubuntu 22.04 later, or maybe do a fresh install of a later Ubuntu LTS version now that my BIOS is accessible again. Right now I'm very happy that my computer is working again, and I'm going to have a beer.